# How Can I Set the Height of a Single UITabelViewCell to a Constant Value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am searching on Google about this but I always find very complex solutions about it. I have a cell with an non editable scrollable UITextView and I just want to increase the height of that cell to a constant value. How can I do it? Actually I am using the next code to add the UITextView to the cell.

```
cell.contentView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
textView.editable = NO;
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.text = self.description;

[cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
[textView release];
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement this method in your delegate: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Thanks jxpx777. Here my own solution. 
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 
 if ((indexPath.section != SECTION_NUMBER)) {
        // Returns the default row height.
  return 44;
    } else {
        // Returns three times the default row height.
  return 44 * 3;
    }
}